# How do I insert mentioned user on embed thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I do the rest of the embed, everything is working except the thumbnail.

This is what I have now:

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
   if(msg.content = "?profile") {
      const profile = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setThumbnail(msg.mentions.users.first().avatarURL)
      msg.reply(profile)
   }
})
```

By the way if you could please tell me how to put the mentioned member server joined date on the embed Description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`displayAvatarURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL):

```js
const profile = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setThumbnail(msg.mentions.users.first().displayAvatarURL());
```

---

As for your second question:

> how do I put the mentioned member server joined date

You can use the [`joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt) property.

Comment: Oh thank you I already tried it but I forgot the ()....